# MySQL - Select first letter including articles (a, an, the)

Tags: mysql

So I understand how to find results if I only want to find the beginning of a column. Like:

```
select * from locations where (loc_name like 'C%')
```

or

```
select * from locations where (loc_name REGEXP '^[C]')
```

What I need to figure out is how to do the same thing, but include anything that is the C. For example, a place called `The Castle` or `The Park Tavern` or anything like that.

When clicking on the letter on a web page, the results should come up with anything with that letter or THE letter.

Comment: This is basic SQL. You should find a tutorial. `SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE  loc_name LIKE '%C%'`

Comment: Do you want to limit to words that start with C? Or really just anything that contains C? Does case matter?

Answer (score 3):

Thats easy if you're gonna look for C or The C just write this:

`Select * from locations where loc_name like 'C%' or upper(loc_name) like 'THE C%';`

try it